# Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/Slider' in {path}

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I imported the Slider:

```
import Slider from '@material-ui/lab/Slider';
```

and have returned  in the render.

The code is not getting compiled and is throwing an error:

> Module not found: Error: `Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/Slider' in
>   {path}`.

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: import {Slider} from 'material-ui'

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You have to install the lab package: `npm install @material-ui/lab`

Answer (score 7):

Updated answer as of February 2021:  Slider has been moved into core, so you should change your import to:

```
import Slider from '@material-ui/core/Slider';
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in the your terminal/ cmd :

npm install @material-ui/lab

After successful installation, restart the server.
It will work properly.
You can check manually in your node_modules/@material-ui. You will find lab folder in it.

Answer (score 1):

Error itself shout a lot.

> Module not found

That means you've to install the `module` if its not part of your project.

lab doesn't come with `material/core`

Just install the lab package through any package manager `NPM` or `YARN`

**npm**

```
npm install @material-ui/lab
```

**yarn**

```
yarn add @material-ui/lab
```

I would suggest to use only one package at a time, And also check if the lock file exist.
Sometimes it conflicts and cause issue with the existing packages.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is the followin (use --save to save the dependencency in package.jso)

```
 npm install @material-ui/lab --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the npm package `npm install @material-ui/lab`.
Incase this doesn't work please check your material-ui/core version and the material-ui/lab version you installed.
You can’t use v3 of @material-ui/core with v4 of @material-ui/lab please upgrade core

## Reference:

1. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16319#issuecomment-504297322,
2. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12124

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with Pagination from **@material-ui/lab/Pagination** and faced the same error because I just installed  **@material-ui/lab** with version **4.0.0-alpha.57** but I was using old version of **@material-ui/core** which was below **4.0.**

I uninstalled **@material-ui/core** and re-installed npm package and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue after installing `@mui/lab` package with material ui 5.0.4.

For yarn users:
`yarn add @mui/lab`

For npm users:
`npm install @mui/lab`

Answer (score 0):

Try to install both `@material-ui/lab` and `@material-ui/core`.

```
npm install @material-ui/lab
npm install @material-ui/core
```

The above tested for `@material-ui/core v4.12` and `@material-ui/lab v4.0`.

You might also need  MUI icons package installed (`npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/71806305