# Cannot find module '@material-ui/lab'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, material-ui

I am building a front-end page where I need @material-ui/lab. After installing the package with npm, I get a typescript error when compiling: `TS2307: Cannot find module '@material-ui/lab' or its corresponding type declarations.`

However, on my front, it returns an error, but I can see the compilation "worked" when clicking on closing the error dialog since I see the material-ui timeline.

Where does this error come from?

`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "front",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
        "@emotion/styled": "latest",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
        "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.61",
...
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

function App() {
  return <Button variant="contained">Hello World</Button>;
}
```

You need to import something like this

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem in an old project of mine, scratching my head a while an found the solution in this post [Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/Slider' in {path}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330865/cant-resolve-material-ui-lab-slider-in-path)

Basically you have to install the package: npm install @material-ui/lab